# Unify [triangle] [rectangle] [shape] [circle] and the like under [geometry]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

The [triangle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/triangle) tag doesn't seem too useful. It has only 4 followers and is about a very broad concept, much like the [sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sum) tag that was discussed yesterday.

Also, per the comments, these tags should probably be removed as well:

[rectangle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rectangle)
[sphere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sphere)
[shape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shape)
[circle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/circle)
[circles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/circles)

Surprisingly the [cube](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cube) tag appears to be legit! Who knew? [cubes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cubes) however, should probably go, too.

EDIT: Adding retag-request tag to retag these questions with the [geometry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/geometry) tag.

Comment: Vi hart will not be happy.

Comment: Generally, the rule of thumb I've seen mentioned on whether or not a tag is a good one is "Can someone be an expert in it".  I highly doubt there are hordes of triangle experts roaming the internet looking for questions to answer.  So I concur, let's kill it.

Comment: how about "square", "sphere" and "shape" tags shouldn't they deserve the same?

Comment: @psubsee2003 I like to think Pythagoras was an expert on triangles. He came up with a pretty decent theorem. Maybe someone on SO is the next Pythagoras in the programming triangles world... We should tidy this up though

Comment: @Joe Maybe I should phrased that like "hordes of experts in programming with triangles".  If Pythagoras shows up, we can send him over to Mathoverflow and Math.SE

Comment: @psubsee2003 It's phrased fine, it's just me being me.. :p

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! My apologies to Ms. Hart.

Comment: "triangle expert"--that's a badge I'd work toward!

Comment: There's at least one high-quality [triangle answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7073558/2970947).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Seems pretty specific to CSS and not really applicable to most of the triangle experts out there.

Comment: @Dukeling Fair enough. Seems like  [tag:polygon] is suspicious in general.

Comment: There is a [tag:geometry] tag. I think these tags should be replace by that one. [tag:Shape]'s definition bothers me. It's a widely used term in GIS, but it often doesn't have anything to do with visuals.

Comment: @hexparrot if you hurry up and get a tag score of 2K by answering 200 questions, you can own your very own gold badge in triangling.  then you can close any triangle question you want as a duplicate.

Comment: @jpmc26 Why did you delete your answer and post a comment instead? I think that's significant enough for an answer.

Comment: @Dukeling 'Cause I have no idea what I'm doing in meta. =( I wasn't even sure if you're supposed to answer burninate requests. I'll bring it back.

Comment: @jpmc26 (I'm not sure either, but I tend to think things than are important enough for the attention an answer gets, that should be voted upon and/or that deserves a discussion of its own should be answers)

Comment: But if we remove triangles, nobody could upvote posts anymore :-(.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the process here. Does this get voted on? Do moderators decide and take action? What happens from here?

Comment: @user1118321 http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/burninate-request/info If I'm reading this correctly, then someone goes through and retags questions until the tag has zero questions, and then it gets cleaned up automatically. Who does so or when is something I couldn't say. Since you agree with the retag, you probably need to retag this question appropriately, though. After that, I have no idea. =D

Comment: @jpmc26 Thanks for the link! I've added the retag-request tag.

Comment: Add [tag:circle] and [tag:circles] to the mix: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285970/synonimize-circle-and-circles

Comment: OK, I've completed the migration of [triangle]. I'll do the others as time goes on. Should we remove [triangle] now that it's been migrated?

Comment: [tag:circles] has now been emptied. [tag:circle] is still there, however.

Comment: All seem dead except [circle], so I added [circle] as a synonym to [geometry].

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I would like to propose that instead of simply burninating all these tags, it may be more useful to replace them with the [geometry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/geometry) tag (with the exception of [cube](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cube), of course).

Answer (score 11):

[cube](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cube) should go all the same. It has at least 3 distinct meanings (multiple meanings is not good for tags), one of which relates to geometry (which should go).

We already have [olap-cube](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/olap-cube) and [data-cube](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data-cube), so all relevant questions should be retagged to that.

If relevant, we should create more tags to deal with the remaining non-cube-shape questions.

[cubes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cubes) similarly refers to all 3 and should go for the same reason.

Comment: Ah, interesting. I didn't know about those. Yeah, retagging seems reasonable then.

Comment: [tag:data-cube] has no wiki description. Maybe you could add one?

Comment: @jpmc26 I don't really have domain experience. If I edit the tag wiki, it would probably be a direct copy from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_cube).

Comment: Start [here](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[cube]+olap) :P

Comment: I think we need to have a cube-shape tag. I've spent some time replacing cube with olap-cube and leaving the shape related ones. That's the only other use of cube I've been seeing, so if we provide shape-cube that'll leave us free to remove cube.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen the [shape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shape) tag on a question where it was relevant.  All of these may be relevant to graphics programming.

Comment: [tag:shape] seems ambiguous to me, since it's a widely used term in GIS as well. That's probably because I deal with GIS a lot. ;)

Comment: I'm a certified shape expert.