# Burninate [square]

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

There's at least four things that the [square](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/square) tag refers to:

- Anything that involves the four-sided shape with 90° angles, whether it be square `<div>`s, squares in a game, or square nodes in a diagram.
- Square brackets (i.e. `[` and `]`)
- The payment processor [Square](https://squareup.com/ca)
- The mathematical operation of multiplying a number by itself, or its inverse (i.e. `x²` and `√x`)

There's no wiki for it yet. Someone tried to add an excerpt related to the payment processing company, but after looking at the tagged questions, I decided to reject the edit as it does not accurately describe or reflect on the contents of the questions.

Perhaps it can be left for questions related to the payment processor, as it doesn't seem necessary for the other ones to be tagged as such.

Comment: I've just come across this useless tag too; perhaps a more punny title would help it along? `It should be no longer be hip to be [square]`?. I agree that the payment processor is the only valid use.

Comment: synonym of: `[`[tag:rectangle]`]` is the only correct solution.

Comment: "Let's be [square] about burninating this"

Comment: "This tag deserves to be burninated, fair and [square]" (maybe reaching a bit)

Comment: @Yakk [No](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254937/1394393).

Comment: It has a wiki now to mean the payment processor, is a burn still relevant?

Comment: Throw the [square] tag in the [square] garbage can... i don't even know that's the best i can think of

Comment: https://www.quora.com/What-programming-language-is-Square-written-in-and-why-is-it-written-in-that-language that is also another version of square

Comment: @SheshankS. The Square payment processor has already been mentioned repeatedly.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I think the [square](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/square) tag should be used for the payment processor. I propose these tags for the rest:

- Square shapes shouldn't really require a tag, at best, a [geometry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/geometry) or [shape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shape) tag should suffice.
- Square brackets - or just [brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/brackets); `()` are called parentheses.
- Mathematical operation - well it's just to the power of two, so it can fall under <s>[indices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/indices)</s>[exponent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exponent).

Comment: That's certainly not an internationally standard usage of "brackets"; here in the UK when people say "brackets" they mean `()`. "parenthesis" means [the kind of phrase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parenthesis_%28rhetoric%29), often delimited with `()` but also sometimes with `-` or `,`.

Comment: @Imm Maybe. I was from London and brackets do indeed mean () for me also. But I guess the take home message is simply 'square brackets', 'parenthesis' or 'brackets' should never be tagged 'square'

Comment: I expect the square tag not to be used at all. [square-reader]

Comment: I'm not sure if indices is the most appropriate for exponents as most of the questions seem to refer to array/collection indices.

Comment: @rink.attendant.6 You're right, I've changed the answer accordingly

Comment: I agree with @dayuloli here - square be used to refer to the specific technology/product, as the other uses have a suitable alternative (and often better) alternative.

Comment: I prefer parentheses, square brackets and (curly) braces.

Comment: Some questions are square as well. Maybe we can tag those questions http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_%28slang%29

Comment: @Netbulae But that definition of square has no programming relation, and I have never heard anyone describe a question as 'square'...Either way, it's simply an adjective. Likewise, we wouldn't tag a question as `difficult`, or else it'll be the most common tag on SO!

Comment: [tag:perfect-square], [tag:square-root], [tag:square-bracket]