# This tag should be [rect]

Tags: discussion, status-declined, burninate-request

[rect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rect) *claims* to be about the `RECT` structure but its questions do not appear to share this idea, since they're generally about rectangles in graphics in whatever different implementations exist. This ambiguity makes the tag's already-dubious usefulness drop to nil. What's more, the fact that there's a rectangle is hardly ever terribly relevant to the problem; it could just as easily be a circle or a hexagon. So much of the reasoning in [Burninate [square]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281668/burninate-square) applies here too.

275 questions, 1 follower; wiki is basically just a geometry textbook excerpt.

Comment: Just a note:  The tag refers to the [RECT structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162897(v=vs.85).aspx) found in the [Windows API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff818516%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  Not to say that that is a reason it shouldn't be burninated though.

Comment: @iCodez: Duly noted. I'm not a Win32 expert by a long shot, and even P/Invoke causes a bit of frustration from time to time.

Comment: See also (Remove [triangle])[https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254937/remove-triangle].  Four other people shared [my curiosity about [rect] and [rectangles]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277705/burninate-ratio#comment121350_277705) on the [ratio] burnination request.  (Also apparently I cannot markdown-link right now.)

Comment: @RobertColumbia: I wholly approve finally coming up with a pun for this. No doubt this is the only reason it was never properly attended to when I first posted it.

Answer (score 7):

Since [RECT is apparently a thing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162897(v=vs.85).aspx) I would suggest we do the following

1. Clean the tag up. Retag the rectangle stuff
2. Rename the tag to [windows-rect]

[rect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rect) 459 Open Qs, 25 watchers

> To be used with RECT structure when using winapi. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162897(v=vs.85).aspx. For questions relating to rectangles not using this api, use the rectangles tag https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rectangles. Use with other relevant tags, such as programming language.