# Tag [square] needs some cleanup

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

[square](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/square) needs some cleanup as the title says. I can see questions related to many things in the [front page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/square?page=1&sort=newest&pagesize=30) like:

- Square API
- The shape square
- Something related to square wave
- Square brackets
- Squaring a number
- Square bullets
- Square root
- Magic squares
- ...

[square](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/square) hasn't got a tag wiki / exerpt too, which makes it too broad.

But I don't think burnination is the best option as there is an API named square. IMO, it needs some retagging and the tag wiki / exerpt needs to be added so that users know when to use this tag.

Comment: The API questions can use the existing [square-connect] tag I think.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281668/burninate-square