# How to rekindle burnination requests that failed to ignite?

Tags: discussion, burninate-system

I came across the rather useless [square](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/square) today, and a quick search showed me a [year-old request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281668/burninate-square) that got nowhere, yet people are still abusing the tag a couple of times a week.

I could, of course, write a short wiki entry to point out that it is for the Square payment processor only (or is it?), and purge random tagging regarding raising to the power two or drawing a box, but surely there must be a better way to bump a burninate request?

Yes, I was tempted to change to a punny title, but that seemed a bit of a cheap tactic...

Comment: Cheap, as in low cost for its effectiveness?  Punny titles pay people for their attention with punishment.  Ya gotta pay to play.

Comment: I am sorry in advance for the useless comment but reading this post's current title made me think of a certain game and i came out with "Stack Souls"

Comment: You could simply drop in to the [SOCVR](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) chatroom, there's a coordinated effort in there for some burninations.

Comment: That request is on the first page of our [search](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&pagesize=50&q=%5bburninate-request%5d%20closed%3ano%20-%5bstatus-*%5d%20hasaccepted%3ano) but as you can see there are others needing our attention. Find the process we follow [here](https://github.com/SO-Close-Vote-Reviewers/SOCVR-RoomInformation/blob/master/burnination.md).

Answer (score 37):

> Yes, I was tempted to change to a punny title, but that seemed a bit of a cheap tactic..

No, writing a punny title is *the* official way to revive burninate requests.

Well, at least [editing a question to bump it back up](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266782/on-meta-how-do-you-get-attention-for-questions-without-an-answer) is one of the official ways of getting more attention for it. And changing the title is a type of edit. And improving the title with a pun is clearly a constructive edit. So....

If you want to actually start the fires ablaze, you should consider editing into the question (or, alternatively, posting as an answer) a more comprehensive justification for why the tag is actively harmful and therefore needs to go. A lot of burninate suggestions on Meta are only 50% there. They successfully identify problematic tags, but they fail to actually [explain the problems and why burnination is the solution](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239191/153008). It is far too easy to fall into the trap of assuming everyone knows what you are thinking.