# Synonimize [circle] and [circles] or retag with [geometry] tag

Tags: support, tags, retag-request, tag-synonym-process

Both tags [circle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/circle) and [circles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/circles) have same meaning.

I'm not sure if tags like [circle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/circle), [square](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/square), [rectangles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rectangles), etc. shouldn't be synonimized even further, as [geometry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/geometry).

Comment: Both [tag:circle] and [tag:circles] seem like utterly useless tags, imo.

Comment: related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254937/remove-triangle ; [rect] and/or [rectangle] have also been discussed.

Comment: @AlexisKing then do what is appropriate. Provide comments, answers, vote to burnitate, retag, whatever. I am only pointing that such tags exist.

Comment: @Deduplicator O.K. so you have edited "remove-triangle" question and now it became a duplicate.