# It's time to cross the [line]

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

I discovered today that there's actually a [line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/line) tag, and 4,000+ questions use it. According to its wiki entry, it's described as:

> The shortest distance between two points. Or, a row of characters in
>   text output.

Seriously?

The [four burnination criteria](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191#239191) are:

1. Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?
2. Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?
3. Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?
4. Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

To which I believe the answers are no, no, no, and no.

Comment: We've reached the end of the [line] ;)

Comment: That tag definitively crossed the [line] ;)

Comment: This tag needs to toe the [line] ;)

Comment: "[Line]s, [line]s, everywhere there's [line]s" - Paul Simon

Comment: I had to google the [line] above

Comment: **Related tag:** [polyline](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/polyline/info) "Polyline in computer graphics is a continuous line composed of one or more line segments." **Proposal:** Retag those questions tagged with [line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/line) with a new tag named `line-geometry`. **Note:** Wikipedia's [disambiguation page for line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line) shows entries for [Line (geometry)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_(geometry)) and [Line (text file)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_(text_file)).

Comment: Isn't there an app called *Line*?

Comment: @DavidRR polyline is **not** a line. the rest of your comment could be posted as an answer.

Comment: the answer to '3.' could be yes.

Comment: Ya, just cross it!!!

Comment: Because you're mine, I cross the line.

Comment: Is there a way to see which tags have been created recently? Garbage collection - aah, I mean burnination - of tags would be faster if we burninate them at the source ;) I guess that more than 50% of new tags shouldn't have been created in the first place...

Comment: @DavidRR There's no need for lines to have their own separate geometry tag. Just change it to [tag:geometry] when that's appropriate.

Answer (score 9):

The ones that actually deal with the geometric math about lines can be retagged with [geometry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/geometry). We've had a number of other burnination requests about geometric figures: [Unify [triangle] [rectangle] [shape] [circle] and the like under [geometry]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254937/1394393). (There's another one solely about [rectangle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rectangle), too, but I don't wanna hunt around for it right now.)

I could also think of some cases where [gis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gis) would be appropriate.