# Does the tag [line] include the app?

Tags: discussion, tags

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47823870/how-does-one-host-a-line-bot-on-heroku) uses the tag [line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/line) in a fashion out of its tag wiki's definition. Simply put, it references the LINE IM app. I would believe this definition to be accurate and within scope, but there may be others who feel differently. I wish for community input on this before I update the tag wiki. Anyways, **how should we update the tag wiki to accommodate this information?**

Comment: Or burn it? Looking at the highly voted questions, the tag has been used in a number of different contexts.

Comment: @Nisarg Yeah, burnination has been [brought up before](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351468/its-time-to-cross-the-line?rq=1), but there wasn't a clear answer on what to do about it. Would it be considered too broad if I brought that argument into my question?

Comment: You don't have to include that since that request has 37 votes. Though it might not be taken up anytime soon because the tag has ~4k questions.

Comment: Does burnination happen manually? I just sort of assumed that there was a bot for that or something.

Comment: One of the mods usually initiate the process. There's some info regarding the process in tag wiki [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/burninate-request/info).